# Android logic behind weightsum

Tags: android

So I have this XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@+id/linearLayoutOuter"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="3.0"
>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_weight="1.0"
>
<Gallery
 android:id="@+id/galleryMain"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="90dp">
</Gallery>
<LinearLayout
 android:id="@+id/linearLayoutInner"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="@layout/gallery_image_background"
/>
</LinearLayout>


<TextView
android:id="@+id/galleryTextView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="2.0"
>
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Currently it sizes correctly, but I don't think that can be right.

The LinearLayout that gets 1.0 out of 3.0 possible weight takes about 2/3 space.
The TextView that gets 2.0 out of 3.0 possible wight takes about 1/3 space.

Is above really how it is meant to work? It sizes like I want, but... Not sure I understand the logic behind it.

Comment: try converting the weight values in integer type, instead of giving it as 1.0, 2.0 give 1, 2

Comment: Use `0dp` on the width or height depending on the direction you want your two views to stretch.

Comment: Using 0dp appears to work :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is above really how it is meant to work?

Given the way you wrote it, yes, but that's why we usually don't write it that way. :-)

The easier-to-understand approach to weights and `android:weightSum` is to have the heights set to `0dp`, not `match_parent`. Then, each child gets a proportion of the available space based on the weights.

So, to get your 2/3 and 1/3 split this way, you would have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@+id/linearLayoutOuter"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="3.0"
>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_weight="2.0"
>
<Gallery
 android:id="@+id/galleryMain"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="90dp">
</Gallery>
<LinearLayout
 android:id="@+id/linearLayoutInner"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="@layout/gallery_image_background"
/>
</LinearLayout>


<TextView
android:id="@+id/galleryTextView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1.0"
>
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Note that:

- You could go with integers here
- You do not need `android:weightSum` in this case, as the sum of your weights already is that value. You would use `android:weightSum` in cases where the sum of your weights is less than the real total, indicating that some portion of the space should remain as whitespace and treated as such (by default, appearing after the children of the `LinearLayout`).

Comment: Thanks! This works. I am still slightly puzzled as to why "match_parent" would not work the same if all controls sharing the height is set to that. But oh well, now I know how to do it correctly :)